# Can a user with admin role get 'Sorry, you are not allowed to move this item to the Trash' error when trashing a post?

Tags: user-roles, errors, trash

I got the `wp_die` error message:

> Sorry, you are not allowed to move this item to the Trash.

on trying to put the post in trash, but when I tried to put it in trash again the `wp_die` error message:

> Error in moving to Trash.

showed up and on refresh I see that the post was deleted. I have the administrator role, so I have the `delete_post` capability. According to this code snippet in `wp-admin/edit.php`, the role with admin should not get any of these errors.

```
foreach ( (array) $post_ids as $post_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'delete_post', $post_id) )
        wp_die( __('Sorry, you are not allowed to move this item to the Trash.') );

    if ( wp_check_post_lock( $post_id ) ) {
        $locked++;
        continue;
    }

    if ( !wp_trash_post($post_id) )
        wp_die( __('Error in moving to Trash.') );

    $trashed++;
}
```

Comment: is the problem with a regular post and not a custom post type created by a plugin ?

Comment: it's with a custom post

Answer (score 1):

When you use `map_meta_cap` with a custom post type (e.g. CPT `book`), the capability `delete_book` is not automatiqualy added to administrators.

then you need to use `add_cap` to add it

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap